# Compute tranformation matrix for odom to base_link depending on tracking camera attached relative to base_link

Tags: ros, transforms

To complete my tf tree, I must broadcast transformation from `odom` to `base_link`. I am receiving position from the tracking camera, which is attached to the camera mount relative to `base_link`.
So, I have a pose from the `tracking_camera_frame`
and I know static transform between `base_link` and `tracking_camera_frame`

```
map
 |
 |
odom
 |
 | ?
 +------base_link
            |
            |
            +----camera_mount
                        |
                        +----tracking_camera_frame
```

I don't know how to express the transformation `odom` to `base_link` if I have two mentioned transformations.

When I read about it on the internet, there is always only an example that with multiplication, you can express a point from one coordinate system relative to another.

However, I probably found a solution in the ZED wrapper for ROS, but I don't understand it.

```
tf2::Transform deltaOdomTf_base = mSensor2BaseTransf.inverse() * deltaOdomTf * mSensor2BaseTransf;
```

According to this, my example should be

```
odom_to_base_link = base_link_to_tracking_camera_frame.inverse() * pose * base_link_to_tracking_camera_frame
```

I would like to understand the background of this calculation. Why is it so, or what is the correct form?

**Update:**

I asked chatGPT, and it told me that for equation `resultTF = deltaTF^-1 * pose * deltaTF`, the deltaTF will be effectively cancelled, and the result will be directly related to parent TF. It is what I want. However, what is the mathematical background of this? I want to understand it step by step.
It looks like `resultTF == pose`, but this is not true. So why must these matrices be applied in this order?

Answer (score 2):

One way is with a utility node I made called 'old_tf_to_new_tf' which is configured with four frames: `lookup_parent` `lookup_child`, `broadcast_parent`, and `broadcast_child`- the first 3 need to exist in your system already, there needs to be an existing chain of transforms between the two lookup frames (they can be parents/childs/distant cousins in either position as long as there is a connection), then broadcast_child is published by the old_tf_to_new_tf node.

For your case you would want a second tracking_camera_frame, call it `tracking_camera_frame_zed` or something else distinct from the one that probably came out of your urdf or similar, and configure the zed node to publish 'odom -> tracking_camera_frame_zed' when it does visual odometry (or whatever, just assuming that based on your reference to zed cameras).  Then the old to new tf node would have:

```
lookup_parent:=tracking_camera_frame
lookup_child:=base_link 
broadcast_parent:=tracking_camera_frame_zed 
broadcast_child:=base_link
```

It does a lookup transform with the two lookup frames, then re-publishes the returned transform out but with the provided broadcast parent and child frames replacing the looked-up ones, mirroring the transform from one part of a tree to another part.

https://github.com/lucasw/tf_demo/blob/old_tf_to_new_tf/src/old_tf_to_new_tf.cpp

There's an example launch file in the package too, trying that out and looking at the tf tree in rviz may help it more clear.

It's possible to call it directly inside your C++ node  (it sounds like you have one) instead of having a separate node, make your own `CopyTransform` instance like in the cpp source linked to above.

Comment: Thank your answer. However, I am looking for a mathematical explanation of mentioned equation. My main issue is to understand it. I already implemented it somehow, but it is unclear how it works. Yes, it is C++, and I am using Realsense T265 but directly from librealsense. I am not using the realsense-ros wrapper.

Comment: https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/matrix/functions/inverse/index.htm shows some of the math, https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/matrix4x4/index.htm mentions how a 4x4 rotation + translation matrix is inverted in a faster way which is also the way tf2 transform does it:  https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/noetic-devel/tf2/include/tf2/LinearMath/Transform.h#L187-L191